# ghostscript does not displaying my .ps file

Tags: macos, ghostscript, postscript

I am sorry for what I imagine is an annoyingly trivial question -- I am technologically challenged.  I was trying to learn a bit of postscript (to draw some fun fractals) but unfortunately, I am stuck already at the hello world stage.  Namely, I have the following simple file called file.ps:

> %!PS 
> newpath 
> 72 72 moveto 
> 200 200 lineto
> stroke
> showpage

Running gs appears to go well but no graphical window opens up.

```
$ gs file.ps

GPL Ghostscript 9.19 (2016-03-23)
Copyright (C) 2016 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software comes with NO WARRANTY: see the file PUBLIC for details.
%%BoundingBox: 71 71 201 201
%%HiResBoundingBox: 71.646467 71.646467 200.353564 200.353564
showpage, press \<return> to continue<<
GS>
```

Somehow, I'm not finding anything useful online with regards to this issue, so I thought I would try asking here.  Any thoughts on how I can get a window to display with gs?  If it is relevant, I am doing all of this on my mac.

```
$ gs -help
    GPL Ghostscript 9.56.1 (2022-04-04)
    Copyright (C) 2022 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
    Usage: gs [switches] [file1.ps file2.ps ...]
    Most frequently used switches: (you can use # in place of =)
     -dNOPAUSE           no pause after page   | -q       `quiet', fewer messages
     -g<width>x<height>  page size in pixels   | -r<res>  pixels/inch resolution
     -sDEVICE=<devname>  select device         | -dBATCH  exit after last file
     -sOutputFile=<file> select output file: - for stdout, |command for pipe,
                                             embed %d or %ld for page #
    Input formats: PostScript PostScriptLevel1 PostScriptLevel2 PostScriptLevel3 PDF
    Default output device: x11alpha
    Available devices:
       alc1900 alc2000 alc4000 alc4100 alc8500 alc8600 alc9100 ap3250 appledmp
       atx23 atx24 atx38 bbox bit bitcmyk bitrgb bitrgbtags bj10e bj10v bj10vh
       bj200 bjc600 bjc800 bjc880j bjccmyk bjccolor bjcgray bjcmono bmp16 bmp16m
       bmp256 bmp32b bmpgray bmpmono bmpsep1 bmpsep8 ccr cdeskjet cdj1600 cdj500
       cdj550 cdj670 cdj850 cdj880 cdj890 cdj970 cdjcolor cdjmono cdnj500 cfax
       chp2200 cif cljet5 cljet5c cljet5pr coslw2p coslwxl declj250 deskjet
       devicen dfaxhigh dfaxlow display dj505j djet500 djet500c dl2100 dnj650c
       docxwrite epl2050 epl2050p epl2120 epl2500 epl2750 epl5800 epl5900
       epl6100 epl6200 eplcolor eplmono eps2write eps9high eps9mid epson epsonc
       escp escpage faxg3 faxg32d faxg4 fmlbp fmpr fpng fs600 gdi hl1240 hl1250
       hl7x0 hpdj1120c hpdj310 hpdj320 hpdj340 hpdj400 hpdj500 hpdj500c hpdj510
       hpdj520 hpdj540 hpdj550c hpdj560c hpdj600 hpdj660c hpdj670c hpdj680c
       hpdj690c hpdj850c hpdj855c hpdj870c hpdj890c hpdjplus hpdjportable ibmpro
       ijs imagen inferno ink_cov inkcov itk24i itk38 iwhi iwlo iwlq jetp3852
       jj100 jpeg jpegcmyk jpeggray la50 la70 la75 la75plus laserjet lbp310
       lbp320 lbp8 lex2050 lex3200 lex5700 lex7000 lips2p lips3 lips4 lips4v
       lj250 lj3100sw lj4dith lj4dithp lj5gray lj5mono ljet2p ljet3 ljet3d ljet4
       ljet4d ljet4pjl ljetplus ln03 lp1800 lp1900 lp2000 lp2200 lp2400 lp2500
       lp2563 lp3000c lp7500 lp7700 lp7900 lp8000 lp8000c lp8100 lp8200c lp8300c
       lp8300f lp8400f lp8500c lp8600 lp8600f lp8700 lp8800c lp8900 lp9000b
       lp9000c lp9100 lp9200b lp9200c lp9300 lp9400 lp9500c lp9600 lp9600s
       lp9800c lps4500 lps6500 lq850 lxm3200 lxm5700m m8510 md1xMono md2k
       md50Eco md50Mono md5k mgr4 mgr8 mgrgray2 mgrgray4 mgrgray8 mgrmono miff24
       mj500c mj6000c mj700v2c mj8000c ml600 necp6 npdl nullpage oce9050 oki182
       oki4w okiibm oprp opvp paintjet pam pamcmyk32 pamcmyk4 pbm pbmraw pcl3
       pclm pclm8 pcx16 pcx24b pcx256 pcxcmyk pcxgray pcxmono pdfimage24
       pdfimage32 pdfimage8 pdfwrite pdfwrite pdfwrite pgm pgmraw pgnm pgnmraw
       photoex picty180 pj pjetxl pjxl pjxl300 pkm pkmraw pksm pksmraw plan
       plan9bm planc plang plank planm plib plibc plibg plibk plibm png16 png16m
       png256 png48 pngalpha pnggray pngmono pngmonod pnm pnmraw ppm ppmraw
       pr1000 pr1000_4 pr150 pr201 ps2write psdcmyk psdcmyk16 psdcmykog
       psdcmyktags psdcmyktags16 psdrgb psdrgb16 pxlcolor pxlmono r4081 rinkj
       rpdl samsunggdi sj48 spotcmyk st800 stcolor t4693d2 t4693d4 t4693d8
       tek4696 tiff12nc tiff24nc tiff32nc tiff48nc tiff64nc tiffcrle tiffg3
       tiffg32d tiffg4 tiffgray tifflzw tiffpack tiffscaled tiffscaled24
       tiffscaled32 tiffscaled4 tiffscaled8 tiffsep tiffsep1 txtwrite uniprint
       x11 x11alpha x11cmyk x11cmyk2 x11cmyk4 x11cmyk8 x11gray2 x11gray4 x11mono
       x11rg16x x11rg32x xcf xes xpswrite
    Search path:
       /opt/local/share/ghostscript/9.56.1/Resource/Init :
       /opt/local/share/ghostscript/9.56.1/lib :
       /opt/local/share/ghostscript/9.56.1/Resource/Font :
       /opt/local/share/ghostscript/fonts :
       /opt/local/share/fonts/default/ghostscript :
       /opt/local/share/fonts/default/Type1 :
       /opt/local/share/fonts/default/TrueType : /usr/lib/DPS/outline/base :
       /usr/openwin/lib/X11/fonts/Type1 : /usr/openwin/lib/X11/fonts/TrueType
    Ghostscript is also using fontconfig to search for font files
    For more information, see /opt/local/share/doc/ghostscript/9.56.1/Use.htm.
    Please report bugs to bugs.ghostscript.com.
```

Comment: @JamesRisner Thanks James! I tried using ghostscript to open those sample files and I obtained the same result.  I could use other applications to view them, but that unfortunately doesn't help my issue .

Comment: Are you running an X Server? You'll need to run an X Server to get a display window from Ghostscript on a Mac. Without a working display device Ghostscript is presumably outputing through the "Bounding Box" device which just prints those numbers.

Comment: The device appears to be the bbox device, which means it is the default device (unless you specified -sDEVICE=bbox on the command line). ordinarily the display device is the default which means that, as luser droog noted, you either have a build of Ghostscript which doesn't include the X display device, or you aren't running an X server. You can find out which devices are available by using "gs --help". Also, that's rather an old version of Ghostscript....

Comment: @KenS Thank you Ken - I tried updating and using a few of the displayed devices with -sDEVICE, but it still is not working for me.  I included the result of running $gs -help

Comment: @JamesRisner Yes that is what I wanted and thank you very much James - that did the trick with xquartz.  Many thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ghostscript has many features including converting to various display devices and printer formats.

When on macOS, if you wish to display in a window you will need [XQuartz](https://www.xquartz.org/) installed and running.